# Proof in Markov chains and mixing times book by Levin and Peres

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I'm reading the book Markov chains and Mixing times by Levin and Peres.

I got stuck in one line of the book. Here is it:

[image]

I don't understand why we can get (1.21). In this post, people said it came from Markov property but I don't know how we use it.

[Understanding the proof of stationary distribution of a markov chain](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1187879/787230)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that if $x=z$, then both sides are zero, so we may assume $x \neq z$.

---

It's just a property of conditional probability that
$$\mathbb{P}_z\{X_t=x, X_{t+1}=y, \tau_z^+ \geq t+1\} = \mathbb{P}_z\{X_t=x,  \tau_z^+ \geq t+1\}\cdot \mathbb{P}_z\{X_{t+1}=y \mid X_t=x, \tau_z^+ \geq t+1\}$$
so it suffices to show
$$\mathbb{P}_z\{X_{t+1}=y \mid X_t=x, \tau_z^+ \geq t+1\} = P(x,y).$$

Now, $$\{\tau_z^+ \geq t+1\} = \{X_1\neq z, X_2 \neq z, \ldots, X_t \neq z\}$$
so that
$$\mathbb{P}_z\{X_{t+1}=y \mid X_t=x, \tau_z^+\geq t+1\} = \mathbb{P}_z\{X_{t+1}=y\mid X_t=x, X_1\neq z, X_2\neq z, \ldots, X_{t-1} \neq z\}$$
(note I've used the assumption that $x\neq z$ here)

It's the Markov property that allows us to simplify this to
$$\mathbb{P}\{X_{t+1}=y \mid X_t=x\}$$
which by homogeneity is $P(x,y)$.